# What is a luxury good?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I've only just started playing Elite: Dangerous, and I've accepted a mission to deliver **Luxury Goods**. However, I don't see a commodity type of **Luxury Goods**. Is there **Luxury Goods** commodity type?  If not, what constitutes a **Luxury Good**?

Comment: In the original Elite, "Luxuries" were something like perfume, coffee or spices, but you only ever traded them as tons of "luxuries". Moderately High value, mostly of interest to richer systems. This might be a bit of a reference to the original game. http://www.iancgbell.clara.net/elite/manual.htm#A38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have accepted a mission to deliver them, you don't need to worry about what they are.  Delivery missions put the cargo into your hold for you to deliver.

If you go to your Cargo tab on the right hand interface panel, you should see the luxury goods listed there (and flagged as mission cargo).